# iOS7/xCode5/CollectionView: how to load images from url instead of local files?

Tags: ios, xcode5

i am new to ios, i read this great tutorial to load local images from an array:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial

Its all working smooth, but that is only with static data, i need to load images from a list of url.

I changed this array: (inside: MyCollectionViewController.m / -viewDidLoad)

```
_carImages = [@[@"IMG_2473.jpg",
                @"IMG_2507.jpg",
                @"IMG_2527.jpg",
                @"IMG_2529.jpg",
                @"IMG_2532.jpg",
                @"IMG_2533.jpg",
                @"IMG_2551.jpg",
                @"IMG_2552.jpg",
                @"IMG_2694.jpg"
              ] mutableCopy];
```

to this one:

```
_carImages = [@[@"http://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/articles/health_tools/baby_skin_care_slideshow/getty_rm_photo_of_babies_shopping.jpg",
                @"http://www.northernillinoiscouponing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Colorful_Shopping_bags.jpg",
                @"https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs057/1105082123206/img/34.jpg",
                @"http://swipetelecom.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/shopping.jpg",
                @"http://1000thriftythings.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/goodwill-pet-section.jpg",
                @"http://msophiapr.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/new-illustration-flat-girls-only1.jpg",
                @"http://swipetelecom.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/shopping.jpg",
                @"http://www.gobol.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/online-shopping.jpg",
                @"http://www.birth.com.au/Birth/files/9c/9c4ed300-0dc0-4c62-a638-d1afb102fcae.jpg",
                @"http://www.islandnutznews.com/upload_pic/resize_1338925187.jpg"
                ] mutableCopy];
```

And this is the code for MyCell: (inside: MyCollectionViewController.m / -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *image;
long row = [indexPath row];

image = [UIImage imageNamed:_carImages[row]];

myCell.imageView.image = image;
//myCell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

//change width of frame
CGRect frame = myCell.imageView.frame;
frame.size.width = 160;
myCell.imageView.frame = frame;


return myCell;
}
```

But its not working out, probably i am missing something here.

Ideally, after getting this sorted out, i will use JSON for populating _carImages array.

Please advice, thank you!

**------------------------------**

**UPDATE**
As per the answer by @AntonStremovskiy below, here's my updated code (incase if someone wanted):

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
MyCollectionViewCell *collectionCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!collectionCell) {
    collectionCell = [[MyCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
}

collectionCell.imageView.image = nil;
NSString *url = [_carImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           collectionCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                       }];
return collectionCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"imageCell";

    ImageCollectionViewCell* collectionCell = [self.imageCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!collectionCell) {
        collectionCell = [[ImageCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
    }

        collectionCell.imageFromInstagram.image = nil;

        NSString *url = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                                collectionCell.imageFromInstagram.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                           }];

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.062 green:0.369 blue:0.689 alpha:0.8f];
        collectionCell.selectedBackgroundView = view;

        return collectionCell;
}
```

Something like that

Comment: Anton's exactly right. In your code you are essentially telling the cell to load an image with the url string. It'll look through bundle and not be able to find it (imageNamed: looks through your bundle for an image with that name). Since it can't find that image it'll be nil and no image will be displayed. The other option for loading an image is loading it from NSData, which is what an NSURL connection will return. If you want to be really fancy you can add an activity monitor and start spinning above the async connection and stop it once data is loaded. You'll also want to handle the error.

Comment: thank you, this worked, i updated my question with the edited code of yours. There is something weird happening i must mention, when testing it on my simulator, images shows up fine but then after a little while some cells goes blank, when i keep scroll up/down then they show up again, and then it goes off again after a little while. Seems bit buggy, is this has to do something with the image? Or is the code has some lags? Thanks!

Comment: @JakeHargus thank you for your comment, i really want to show that loading spinner when loading images, that would really help user to see some activity going on. Can you please share the code/link with me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to to put some fake image for placeholder instead of nil.

Comment: Looks like you're using a custom cell from your code (not using the UICollectionViewCell class). Just drag and drop a UIActivityIndicator on your cell. Wire it up by control dragging the the activity monitor from your cell to your ImageCollectionViewCell class and create an IBOutlet for it. Call it something like "spinner". Highlight it in IB and go to the attributes inspector. Check "Hides When Stopped". Right under the line where you instantiate the cell (3rd line) put in "[collectionCell.spinner startAnimating];"

Comment: The line right after where you set the image (collectionCell.imageFromInstagram.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];) do "[collectionCell.spinner stopAnimating];" That should do it.